# Bootstrap grid column size not working with "white-space: nowrap;"

Tags: html, css, html-table, bootstrap-grid

I am currently working on a page containing an html table and I manage columns width with bootstrap grid. Here is a small example reproducing the situation I am struggling with :

https://jsfiddle.net/ggu5Lpc0/45/

I have based my work on the bootstrap nested columns example.

```
<tr class="row">
        <td class="col-xs-4 title">Rambo</td>
        <td class="col-xs-1 synopsis">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10 synopsis-text">
              A movie with Stalone shooting everywhere and wearing a bandana !
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <a class="synopsis-link">
                read
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col-xs-7 note">12 / 10</td>
</tr>
```

It worked until I decide to change the display of texts inside the second column : Put each text cells in one line only and hide its overflow (with ellipsis).

```
.synopsis-text {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then it seems that the width properties applied by bootstrap on each table cells has stopped working since I have used css property "white-space: nowrap;".

How can I keep columns width set, and put those texts shorten with ellipsis and in one line only (also keep each links of the same line) ?

Why is it not working currently ? I would like to understand !